# Esclarecimento sobre o content-type do jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codificação-de-caracteres

Qual seria a diferença/utilidade de se utilizar:

```
beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
   jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1')
}
```

e `contentType: 'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1'`, 
sendo que o contentType apenas não funciona.

De acordo com a documentação do jQuery, deveria funcionar.